# MobileVLCKit iOS UniversalBinary Versions

Tags: ios, vlc, libvlc

Here are precompiled MobileVLCKit Universal Binaries for iOS: http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/iOS/?C=M;O=A

There are a lot of different versions like 0009, 0555, 0622, 1748 and so on.

Can anyone explain what is the difference between them and which should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are development versions of our library, which we are building up to 3 times per week. Therefore, the newer the date, the newer the build. This is useful if you are waiting for a specific fix or feature to become available without having to compile it yourself.

Comment: Dear @feepk, what is the difference between them and where can I find stable compiled universal binary? Thank.

Comment: A stable UB is available through CocoaPods. This is the best and most reliable way. For the difference between builds, this is totally unpredictable as it just reflects the current development process. If you don't follow it, you won't know the differences.

Comment: @feepk : is there a possibility to retrieve the sources and project files from the universal binary so we can rebuild it ourselves ?

Comment: sure, it's available on git.videolan.org in the VLCKit repository.

Comment: Dear @feepk UB on [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/pods/MobileVLCKit) is years old... Is it still the best option?

Comment: We will provide an update for the cocoapods distribution along with the next desktop release of VLC within a few days (if everything stays on schedule) :)